# Using nginx and gunicorn to serve django

Tags: python, django, url, nginx, gunicorn

I am receiving the error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named Interest.urls
```

even though my settings file has been changed several times:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

or
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'interest.urls'

I keep getting the same error, as if it doesn't matter what I put in my settings file, it is still looking for Interest.urls, even though my urls file is located at Interest(django project)/interest/urls.py

I have restarted my nginx server several times and it changes nothing, is there another place I should be looking to change where it looks for my urls file?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the same error running the development server?

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart my supervisorctl, which restarted the gunicorn server which was actually handling the django files

Answer (score 0):

There's not need to restart nginx, you can do these steps:

1. Install fabric (pip install [fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric))
2. Create a "restart" function into fabfile.py that has the following:

   def restart():
       sudo('kill -9 `ps -ef | grep -m 1 \'[y]our_project_name\' | awk  \'{print $2}\'`')
3. Call the function through:

   $ fab restart
4. Optional, you might want to add the command into a script with your password just adding "-p mypass" to fabric command

That will kill all your gunicorn processes allowing supervisord to start them again.